# How to replace empty slots in a Template with strings in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function which takes a Template "xs" and replaces the empty slots with the strings in "strs". Below is an example:

```
template {}word{}{} ["9", "2", "7"] = 9word27
```

I'm looking for any help that may be useful. Below is what I have so far:

```
template :: Template -> [String] -> String
template (Template xs) strs =
```

Some helper functions:

```
data Slot = Slot
          deriving (Show, Eq)

data Template =
  Template [Either String Slot]
  deriving Eq

instance Show Template where
  show (Template xs) =   concat $ map f xs
    where f (Left x) = x
          f (Right x) = "{}"
data Def =
  Def [Template]
  deriving Eq
```

We can always assume that the number of slots is equivalent to the number of strings.

Comment: What if numbers of slots and strings differ?

Comment: @Yuuri it's allowed to crash. For this case we just need to worry about if the number of slots is equal to the number of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution using the `State` monad is possible:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State 

template :: Template -> [String] -> String
template (Template xs) strs = evalState (foldM f [] xs) strs where 
  f s (Left s') = return (s ++ s')
  f s Right{} = state $ \(r:rs) -> (s++r,rs)
```

As per your requirements, this crashes (with a pattern match error) in case the number of slots and strings differ.

Comment: I get an error:
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: MonadState [[a]] m
(Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)